# MUC Light needed separate message thread?

Tags: android, xmpp, multiuserchat

I am newly reading MUC and XMPP. In Normal MUC, it create separate message thread.
Even XMPP mentioned best practice to for message thread.
https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0201.html#motivation

My problem is when we create new single group say GroupA, xmpp creates two different groups, GroupA and message thread group. so when I want to fetch offline message for 50 groups, then silently it is fetching 100 group's messages.

Which make heavy operation on our android app.

Therefore I want to work with MUC Light, but I am sure whether I have to use message thread for MUC light also.

Also, how one can use MUC light over existing normal MUC with android and iOS as a client.

Is it mandatory to create separate message thread to fetch offline messages in MUC Light as well in normal MUC?

And major implementation differences between MUC and MUC light?